# TMC2130 does not work properly

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver, teensy

Great title, I know.
I have a driver board connected to a really small stepper motor. When I run it in step / dir mode it works.

But as soon as I connect either SCLK or MOSI the motor turns at double the rate, TMCs CS is low it turns in full speed and when CS is high the motor acts completely up, turns into the end stops, changes direction half way...

The serial output is always 1, I guess the chip simply does not send any data. With a pull-up I get all ones and when removing it I get either 0 or random nonsense.

I can't for the life of me figure out anything. It simply behaves completely weird and I have no idea whatsoever, why that thing simply does not work with the most basic "hello world" of motion controllers.

Thing I don't get. Why does the motor turn faster when connecting *something*? Why does the chip don't output any data at all? Why does it turn back and forth wildly?

My connections are all correct, I don't have open signal lines, my connections are not flaky and the power supply is perfectly fine.

I run the show on a Teensy 2.0++ with Arduino, since I want to understand the driver before working with a real language. The Library is TMC2130Stepper

[TMC2130 Datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet_Rev1.12.pdf)

[SilentStepStick Datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/Eval_Drawings/SilentStepStick-TMC2130_v10.pdf)

There is no schematic. It's simply the step interface, power supply and the ISP interface...

Arduino Code

```
#include <TMC2130Stepper.h>

#define PIN_LED PIN_D6
#define PIN_STP PIN_F0
#define PIN_DIR PIN_F1
#define PIN_EN  PIN_B5
#define PIN_CS  PIN_B4

TMC2130Stepper stepper = TMC2130Stepper(PIN_EN, PIN_DIR, PIN_STP, PIN_CS);

bool dir = true;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN_STP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_DIR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);

  stepper.begin();
  stepper.SilentStepStick2130(20);
  stepper.stealthChop(1);

  digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PIN_STP, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(200);
  digitalWrite(PIN_STP, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(200);
  
  uint32_t ms = millis();
  static uint32_t last_time = 0;
  
  if ((ms - last_time) > 2000) {
    if (dir) {
      Serial.println("Dir -> 0");
      //stepper.shaft_dir(0);
      digitalWrite(PIN_DIR, dir);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Dir -> 1");
      //stepper.shaft_dir(1);
      digitalWrite(PIN_DIR, dir);
    }
    
    dir = !dir;
    
    Serial.println(stepper.GCONF(), BIN);
    last_time = ms;
  }
}
```

[image: sketchy breadboard setup]

I'm not the biggest fan of imgur, but it's not too important, just some additional view.

[Without SPI, works great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ygfw.jpg)

[With SPI, obviously does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ksN.jpg)

Comment: We seem to be missing the schematic, link to the datasheets and maybe some code?

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: It's simply boilerplate example stuff. Nothing custom, nothing weird. Just a simple test to get the driver somewhat running. The code is directly from the libraries author (with pinModes added, since it didn't work without)

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a schematic of the whole setup, and maybe even a photo.

Comment: It's just a breadboard with nothing but these two modules. I'll post a photo in a moment. I'm aware of the issues with breadboards and tried a few different locations and routed the wires differently without any effect whatsoever

Comment: But I'm already weirded out by the fact that connecting SPI speeds the motor up. And the back and forth movement, where I don't actually use SPI after setup

Comment: @pgvoorhees just added a photo

Comment: I'd seriously look at using a separate power supply for the driver an motor. You might be causing some kind of reset condition in the MCU.

Comment: Could be ground bounce due to your 0v wiring.  Put an electrolytic cap across the supply to the motor driver. Also try another power supply rather than USB. Feed the supply wiring to the driver not to the teensy. Where you see solid wires, I see inductors. Start switching current at high speed and the effect becomes significant.  Note ‘Arduino’ is not a language - it is a framework! It’s all just C/C++.

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Kartman I suspected to come across like a newbie with such a question. Yes, I know what Arduino is, sorry for the slip of the tongue. We are talken 0,002A. And not really fast switching, so I don't see an issue with inductance. Also wouldn't explain why it works without SPI ;)

Comment: @pgvoorhees I don't think so, as it is a ridiculously low power motor. Anyway. I implemented your tips and as I suspect it's nothing electrical (seemingly). I placed Elkos in front of the driver, power it from a separate power supply and still get the same issues

Comment: There could be a number of issues conspiring to cause your problem. Whilst you may not perceive there is an issue, what have you done to measure it? Otherwise you’re just guessing. I’ve lost count of the times where my flawed thinking has been proven wrong.

Comment: You are right. I cannot measure a lot, based on my sparse equipment. And I'm open for having missed something obvious. As a professional Software Developer for about 15 years I learned exactly that. Most of the time the bug lies between screen and chair.

Comment: Nevertheless. Why does it work without SPI lines attached and why does it start to act up *with* SPI? Why does the motor move faster as soon ass I connect SCLK or MOSI? That does not point to an electrical issue, IMHO

Comment: It sounds like I'm sending commands that disturb the controller. But the only command I would've sent (by `stepper.shaft_dir()` is commented out because it did not work at all. That's another issue and I didn't even come around to work on that one

Comment: I added two videos. There you can see for yourself what the effect looks like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When things don't make sense, then it's time to RTFM. According to the TMC2130 datasheet, the spi pins (and others) are configuration inputs.

Section 24 of the datasheet explains.

To select edit[SPI] standalone mode, you need to ground the SPI_MODE pin.

Comment: "To activate standalone mode, tie pin SPI_MODE to GND. SPI is off." That means to select stand alone mode you need to tie SPI_MODE to ground. I'm planning to use it either in step/dir mode (which uses SI for configuration). Refer to section 1, operation mode 1

Comment: yes, I did state the spi_mode backwards. dyslexia rules KO?

Comment: Thanks, that was the push in the right direction. The board was apparently shipped in standalone mode. Now I understand the changes in speed, since I had config pins instead of an SPI input. I removed the jumper and after some tinkering and yet another misplaced pin I got it to run! I'd like to accept your answer if you correct it.

Comment: And thanks for your patience ;-)

Comment: we've all been there. Do I get the answer vote?

Comment: Well, it's still wrong as an answer, but actually I don't care